# What hackers do in the darknet?

Tags: attack-prevention, darknet

What do hackers do in the darknet? I know that there are some "hacker services" that they can make some money, but I wonder if there are more interesting things, like forums about specific targets. I'm not a hacker or something, but I wonder if there is some way to know about attacks before they will happen.

Comment: there are services that will scan the *dark web* for this type of info, but your title question does not match your body question

Comment: Mostly, they do the same sorts of things they do on the clear web, just without worrying about who might see them.  99% of the deep web is actually a pretty boring place.

Comment: @schroeder Guess that's why it got deleted. Do you remember what was factually incorrect please ? I'd like to correct this(theese) point(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do anything they want, including but not only:

- Sharing hacking tools
- Developing hacking tools
- Organizing hacking meetings/ info sharing sessions
- Organizing large scale attacks
- Offering hacking payed services (P2HK - pay2hack)
- Creating custom hacking tools on demand (payed service)
- Recruiting new hackers